# The compiler failed with error code -1073741502 and the ApplicationPoolItentity is already set

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors, iis-7

Ι have Windows Server 2008 R2 system having IIS 7, as the live/production server. My application is using the ASP.MVC 3 framework. Currently, when I am navigating between the views of the application, some views don't work and the following error message appears:

**The compiler failed with error code -1073741502**

I have done some research on the web and I found that you have to set the application pool identity. The problem is that the application pool already has an legitimate identity. What I am currently do in order to fix the problem is to stop the site, recycle the application pool and start the site again. After that the previous views work correctly but there is always a change another view to crash.

Does anybody know what may cause this problem and what I have to do in order to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: This maybe helps?- perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743576/compiler-error-message-the-compiler-failed-with-error-code-1073741502-possib

Comment: Also check error logs and event viewer to see if you can get more detailed message.